# MySQL : When stored procedure parameter name is the same as table column name

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

Let's say a have a stored procedure SetCustomerName which has an input parameter Name, and I have a table customers with column Name.
So inside my stored procedure I want to set customer's name. If I write

```
UPDATE customers SET Name = Name;
```

this is incorrect and I see 2 other ways:

```
UPDATE customers SET Name = `Name`;
UPDATE customers SET customers.Name = Name;
```

First one works, but I didn't find in documentation that I can wrap parameters inside ` characters. Or did I miss it in the documentation (link is appreciated in this case).

What other ways are there and what is the standard way for such a case? Renaming input parameter is not good for me (because I have automatic object-relational mapping if you know what I mean).

**UPDATE:**

So, there is a link about backticks (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) but it's not explained deep enough how to use them (how to use them with parameters and column names).

And there is a very strange thing (at least for me): You can use backticks either way:

```
UPDATE customers SET Name = `Name`;
//or
UPDATE customers SET `Name` = Name;
//or even
UPDATE customers SET `Name` = `Name`;
```

and they all work absolutely the same way.

Don't you think this is strange? Is this strange behavior explained somewhere?

Answer (score 22):

Simplest way to distinguished between your parameter and column (if both name is same) is to add table name in your column name.

```
UPDATE customers SET customers.Name = Name;
```

Even you can also add database prefix like

```
UPDATE yourdb.customers SET yourdb.customers.Name = Name;
```

By adding database name you can perform action on more than 1 database from single store procedure.

Answer (score 7):

I think that your first example is actually backwards. If you're trying to set the "Name" column to the "Name" input parameter, I believe it should be:

```
UPDATE customers SET `Name` = Name;
```

And for the second example, you can set table aliases the same way that you do in all other statements:

```
UPDATE customers AS c SET c.Name = Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily correct, but a fair way to better argument/parameter management, as well readability with easier understanding, especially while working with the SQL;

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spTerminalDataDailyStatistics; DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE spTerminalDataDailyStatistics(
    IN TimeFrom DATETIME, 
    IN DayCount INT(10), 
    IN CustomerID BIGINT(20)
) COMMENT 'Daily Terminal data statistics in a date range' BEGIN
    # Validate argument
    SET @TimeFrom := IF(TimeFrom IS NULL, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00'), TimeFrom);
    SET @DayCount := IF(DayCount IS NULL, 5, DayCount);
    SET @CustomerID := CustomerID;
    
    # Determine parameter
    SET @TimeTo = DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@TimeFrom, INTERVAL @DayCount DAY), INTERVAL -1 SECOND);

    # Do the job
    SELECT          DATE_FORMAT(TD.TerminalDataTime, '%Y-%m-%d') AS DataPeriod, 
                    COUNT(0) AS DataCount, 
                    MIN(TD.TerminalDataTime) AS Earliest, 
                    MAX(TD.TerminalDataTime) AS Latest
    FROM            pnl_terminaldata AS TD
    WHERE           TD.TerminalDataTime BETWEEN @TimeFrom AND @TimeTo
        AND         (@CustomerID IS NULL OR TD.CustomerID = @CustomerID)
    GROUP BY        DataPeriod
    ORDER BY        DataPeriod ASC;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL spTerminalDataDailyStatistics('2021-12-01', 2, 1801);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using backticks in MySQL query syntax is documented here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

So yes, your first example (using backticks) is correct.

Comment: That is a way of doing it, I know this answer is older than me. seems `@` is not a valid prefix for procedure parameters, is there any other valid character that I can add instead? well, other than `$`, I don't want to mix those names with my php variables either.

Comment: backticks only help if dealing with keywords. `Name` and ` Name ` are the same thing, so Name = ` Name ` will always be true

Answer (score -1):

Here is the link you are asking for:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html
The backticks are called "identifier quote" in MySql