# Call a stored function in mysql,But get an error:Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, function

In mysql database,I have a table called 'usertest' which has some user information stored in it.  And I create a UDF called 'getId' successfully.  This is how it created:

```
create function getId(name varchar(255))
returns int
begin
declare id_found int;
set id_found=(select Id from usertest where Name=name);
return id_found;
end
```

It should be OK.However,when I call

```
select getId('mike');
```

mysql engine reports an error:

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row.
```

But in table usertest I have only one row where Name='mike'.That's wired.Someone can tell me why? Thank you in advance  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column names and variables are case-insensitive, so `Name` and `name` are the same thing. It's not comparing the `Name` column with the `name` variable, it's comparing the `name` variable with itself, so it's always true.

Use a different name for the function parameter.

```
create function getId(name_param varchar(255))
returns int
begin
declare id_found int;
set id_found=(select Id from usertest where Name=name_param);
return id_found;
end
```

or use a table name prefix.

```
create function getId(name varchar(255))
returns int
begin
declare id_found int;
set id_found=(select Id from usertest where usertest.Name=name);
return id_found;
end
```

See [MySQL : When stored procedure parameter name is the same as table column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866144/mysql-when-stored-procedure-parameter-name-is-the-same-as-table-column-name)

Comment: @吴环宇 Please accept with the green check mark :p  (it is right under the up down arrows) ... the green thing seen on the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page