# My mySQL stored add update delete procedure replaces the last entry in the table whenever I add a new entry

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

Experienced with Oracle and Microsoft SQL, but super new to mySQL and have never encountered this problem before. Any thoughts? Code below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAddUpdateDelete_Product (IN productId INT, IN title VARCHAR(200), IN description VARCHAR(200), IN price FLOAT, IN categoryId INT, IN toDelete BIT)
BEGIN 
    IF productId = 0 THEN                                                           -- Add
        IF EXISTS(SELECT productId FROM Product WHERE title = title AND description = description AND price=price and categoryId = categoryId) OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT categoryId FROM Category WHERE categoryid=categoryid) THEN
            SELECT -1;
        ELSE 
            INSERT INTO Product (productTitle, description, price, categoryId) VALUES (title, description, price, categoryId);
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
        END IF;
    END IF;
    IF toDelete = 1 THEN                                                            -- Delete
        IF EXISTS(SELECT reviewId FROM Review WHERE productId=productId) THEN
            UPDATE Product SET toDelete = 1 WHERE productId = productId;
            SELECT 0;
        ELSE 
            DELETE FROM Product WHERE productId = productId;
            SELECT 0; 
        END IF;
    END IF; 

    IF EXISTS(SELECT productId FROM Product WHERE productId=productId) THEN         -- Update
        UPDATE Product SET productTitle=title, description=description, price=price, categoryId=categoryId;
        SELECT productId;
    ELSE
        SELECT -1;
    END IF;
END $$
```

Comment: Realized after running it a couple more times it actually replaces every single entry with the data I want to add. Is this some weird thing about how if statements work in mySQL?

Comment: You MUST specify table alias for each field used because the server cannot distinguish where is a table field and where is a variable, and variable masks a field. I.e. not `WHERE productId = productId` (which is always TRUE until the variable is NULL) but `WHERE Product.productId = productId`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out. I didn't realize using SELECT doesn't work like using a return in a function. Updated code below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAddUpdateDelete_Product (IN productId INT, IN title VARCHAR(200), IN description VARCHAR(200), IN price FLOAT, IN categoryId INT, IN toDelete BIT)
BEGIN 
    IF toDelete = 0 THEN                                                            -- Add/Update
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT categoryId FROM Category c WHERE c.categoryid=categoryid) THEN
            SELECT -1;
        ELSE 
            IF productId = 0 THEN
                INSERT INTO Product (productTitle, description, price, categoryId) VALUES (title, description, price, categoryId);
                SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS productId;
            ELSE
                UPDATE Product SET Product.productTitle = title, Product.description = description, Product.price = price, Product.categoryId = categoryId WHERE Product.productId = productId;
                SELECT productId;
            END IF; 
        END IF;
    END IF;
    IF toDelete = 1 THEN -- Delete
        IF EXISTS (SELECT productId FROM product WHERE Product.productId = productId) THEN
            IF EXISTS(SELECT reviewId FROM Review WHERE Review.productId=productId) THEN
                UPDATE Product SET toDelete = 1 WHERE Product.productId = productId;
                SELECT 0;
            ELSE 
                DELETE FROM Product WHERE Product.productId = productId;
                SELECT 0; 
            END IF;
        ELSE 
            SELECT -1;
        END IF;
    END IF; 

END $$
```

Comment: This code still won't work.`productId = productId` will **always** be true as MySQL will interpret both `productId` as being the column in the table. You need to change the name of your input variable so that it is not the same as a column name.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I'm so used to doing @productId so I forgot to change this over. I think I'm going to just put Product.productId to resolve this so that I can still use the same name in the procedure for convenience sake.

Comment: Are you sure? I did exactly that and it worked just fine through debugging and multiple tests. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866144/mysql-when-stored-procedure-parameter-name-is-the-same-as-table-column-name. For me, productId is not interpreted as the column. Unsure what version of SQL you are using

Comment: Apparently not... I'll delete that comment